# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; BUT WHERE

Tags: php, jquery

I'm getting this error but i can't see what is wrong. I need a little help.
I've tried everything: looked for illegal characters, erasing the semi colon but i can't fix  it anyway.

```
(function(){


$.ajax({
dataType:           "json",
url:                "prueba.php",
type:               "get",
data:               "t=javascript",
success:function(inf){

    var div += "<span class='carpeta'>";//<-- here is where the error comes but i dont see anything!
    div =+ "<span class='titulo'>"+inf["categoria"]+"<h2>"+inf["titulo"]+"</h2></span>";//cerrando titulo
    div =+"<span class='mascara'>"; 
    div =+"<h2>"+inf["titulo"]+"</h2>"; 
    div =+ "<p>"+info["descripcion"]+"</p>";
    div =+ "<a onclick('tutorial_numero("+1+")') href='javascript:void(0)'>Leer mas</a>";
    div =+"</span>"; //cerrando el span de la class mascara
    div =+ "</span>";//cerrando el span de la class carpeta


    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = "porque tio";
    alert("ola k ase")
}
});

})();
```

the php code

```
<?php


if(isset($_GET["t"]))

{



require 'conexion.php';

$getConexion = new conexion();

$conexion_mysql  = $getConexion->mysql();

$id_tutorial = $_GET["t"];$query = "SELECT titulo,contenido_tutorial,descripcion,categoria FROM tituriales WHERE tags LIKE '%$id_tutorial%'";

    $ejecutar_query = $conexion_mysql->prepare($query);

    $ejecutar_query->execute();

        $enviar = $ejecutar_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($enviar as $resultado)
        {

            $f['titulo'] = $resultado['titulo'];
            $f['contenido'] = $resultado['contenido_tutorial'];
            $f['descripcion'] = $resultado['descripcion'];

            if($resultado['categoria']=="web");
            {
                $f['categoria'] = "<img src='../pc.png' />";
            }
            if($resultado['categoria']=="desktop")
            {
                $f['categoria'] = "@";
            }
            if($resultado['categoria']=="ambos")
            {
                $f['categoria'] = "klk";
            }

            //echo $f["categoria"];

            echo json_encode($f);

        }



}



?>
```

Comment: `var div += "<span class='carpeta'>";` gives a syntax error, unexpected `+=`

Comment: no, the same error, I tried before but it didnt work.

Comment: Hi Einer, welcome to SO. I'd like to point out some things that will help improve your chances of getting a good answer in the future. You stated your problem clearly and included the offending code, which is very good, but you need to pay attention to how your post is formatted: The code formatting of the PHP part was/is broken and made the post very hard to read. You will also attract more people with better tagging: "javascript" is far more relevant to your question than "jquery", but if in doubt, using both is OK.

Comment: After changing `var div +=` to `var div =`, you can't get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shane Andrade already gave you one part of your answer, but that doesn't actually fix the error you get first:

```
var div += "<span class='carpeta'>";
```

This line is invalid all on its own, no other code necessary to see that. `div` is not defined yet, but you try to add something to it, since `div += x` is just shorthand for `div = div + x`. Just assign the string here:

```
var div = "<span class='carpeta'>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string concatenation operators aren't correct. Replace `=+` with `+=`

```
(function(){


$.ajax({
dataType:           "json",
url:                "prueba.php",
type:               "get",
data:               "t=javascript",
success:function(inf){

    var div += "<span class='carpeta'>";//<-- here is where the error comes but i dont see anything!
    div += "<span class='titulo'>"+inf["categoria"]+"<h2>"+inf["titulo"]+"</h2></span>";//cerrando titulo
    div +="<span class='mascara'>"; 
    div +="<h2>"+inf["titulo"]+"</h2>"; 
    div += "<p>"+info["descripcion"]+"</p>";
    div += "<a onclick('tutorial_numero("+1+")') href='javascript:void(0)'>Leer mas</a>";
    div +="</span>"; //cerrando el span de la class mascara
    div += "</span>";//cerrando el span de la class carpeta


    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = div;

}
});
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) are wrong:

- The first one, in the [declaration and initialisation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) of the variable, should be a single `=`
- The following ones, shorthand assignment and concatenation, should be `+=` instead of `=+`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PHP doesn't return json. I think you should debug PHP script.

Comment: Accessing the `inf` variable when it's invalid in the success handler would.

Comment: @CosminPascu The JavaScript has a syntax error: it's nothing to do with the return value in the success function, nor would the *value* of `inf` cause a *syntax* error--the JavaScript has to actually *parse* before the function can execute.

Comment: Dave Newton, damn i don't know, but it does for Jquery File Upload, fabric.js and lots of other libs. But it looks like I was wrong... Well... my bad.